# Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 Diagnostic CPU Usage

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cpu-usage, debug-diagnostic-tool

I'm trying to use Diagnostics Tools Usage CPU to CPU Profiling but when Break All the Call Tree takes a long time to show results, and in some cases not shown. This is a Visual Studio normal behavior of all?

[image: CPU Profiling]

Answer (score 0):

The amount of time to build a call tree depends on several factors: e.g. range of time selected, depth of call tree (number of nodes) and number of symbols to be resolved. In particular, if you enable "Filter > Show External Code" option and enable symbol server via "Debug > Options > Symbols" it will take significantly longer to build a call tree because symbols will be resolved for external code as well. I'd say if showing external code is disabled building a call tree for "average" scenario takes about tens of seconds (but it is very rough estimation of course and not a rule).